# how to get a year and day of the year by using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

how to fetch a year and day of the year  using query in sql server 2008

Ex:

```
11:  YY (Year)
292: Day of the year .31 + 28 +31 + 30 + 31 + 30 +31 + 31 +30 +19: 19th October being the 292 day in this year
```

output required as

```
11, 292
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT RIGHT(YEAR(GETDATE()),2), DATEPART (DAYOFYEAR,GETDATE())
```

Comment: +1 And the first expression could also be `YEAR(GETDATE()) % 100`.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
select 
   year(thedatetime) - 2000, 
   1 + datediff(day, cast(year(thedatetime) as varchar(4)) + '0101', thedatetime)
```